# How to authenticate AWS user on specific host inside private cloud

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-rds

Say I have a server in my basement that I want to replicate to an RDS database. To do so, I add a user in my `pg_hba.conf` file like:

```
hostssl all             replica         64.222.124.22    md5
```

That works! Until the IP address changes.

So I tried putting the AWS host there instead:

```
hostssl all             replica         my-db.random-string.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com    md5
```

But that fails with logs like:

```
2019-03-01 11:50:13.205 PST [28518] replica@server DETAIL:  Client IP address resolved to "ec2-64-222-124-22.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", forward lookup not checked.
2019-03-01 11:50:13.251 PST [28519] replica@server FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "64.222.124.22", user "replica", SSL off
```

And when I do a reverse DNS request on the IP:

```
↪ host 64.222.124.22
49.221.155.35.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ec2-64-222-124-22.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

So I gather that it's failing to resolve the IP address of the connection back to hostname I put in my `pg_hba.conf` file. I *could* put the root domain name in there like so:

```
hostssl all             replica         .rds.amazonaws.com    md5
```

But that kind of defeats the purpose of limiting to a single IP address/host if all of AWS can connect to my server.

Is there a trick to use here to allow resolution to work properly with a hostname from AWS?

I'd really rather not set up a proxy between my two servers just to give one of them a static IP. I looked at AWS elastic IPs, but they can't be assigned to an RDS instance.

Comment: If your DB is not actually in your basement, but rather behind a firewall, you could create a VPN Tunnel from the VPC to the firewall and connect using the private IP address. I may be able to assist with that if the DB is indeed not in your basement.

Comment: Well, yes and no. The server is part of a very small data center in our basement. Creating new servers there isn't out of the question, though it's not our first choice. Also, I didn't think this was relevant, but whatever solution we come up with needs to allow access from RDS instances *outside* of our AWS account. We're an open data org and so we're using logical replication between our server and customer servers to share the data.

Comment: Shameless plug if you're looking at creating a VPN tunnel: https://medium.com/@nZenitram/connecting-an-aws-vpc-to-your-vpn-from-the-cloud-to-the-colo-ed1f2985ccf1

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql does a reverse DNS lookup first when validating pg_hba.conf. Therefore it is important what the reverse DNS is. This also means that this wouldn''t work:

```
hostssl all             replica         .rds.amazonaws.com    md5
```

You could do:

```
hostssl all             replica         .us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com    md5
```

But as you correctly stay, that would leave a very open configuration that would allow any computer running in that region of AWS, to connect with the right md5 password.

That leaves essentially two different options for solving this.

**Option 1 - Private networking and a VPN**

Using AWS VPC's you can set up a private network, and subnet groups for your RDS instance, where it will be assigned IP addresses in an IP space that you can control. Let's say you have a subnet of `10.10.10.0/24`. That would mean you can then post `10.10.10.0/24` in your `pg_hba.conf`. This would require some sort of VPN set up between the VPC and your server.

Depending on the type of networking equipment you have in your basement, you might be able to use the [AWS Site-to-site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html). Alternatively, you could use other solutions shelf solutions such as [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/extending-vpn-connectivity-to-amazon-aws-vpc-using-aws-vpc-vpn-gateway-service/) or [WireGuard](https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-to-configure-wireguard/).

**Option 2 - Dynamically updating `pg_hba.conf`**

If you don't want the extra complexity of a VPN. You could have a script every 5 minutes query the hostname `my-db.random-string.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` and then update pg_hba.conf as necessary and send a SIGHUP signal to postgres. This is not the prettiest solution, but should allow it to work semi-automatically. If no downtime on that connection is required, then this is unlikely to be the ideal solution.

Comment: Sorry, there's another piece of the puzzle I didn't think was relevant, but apparently is. We use pg logical replication between our server and a customer server. Currently that uses the IP address to authenticate (problems!). They've got an RDS server that we're replicating changes to (we are an open data org, so sharing our whole database is our purpose). Would it be possible to get their server in the VPN too?

Comment: Thank you for the information! I didn't know about AWS VPN solutions. They do look really complicated though.

Comment: Yeah, you could add multiple VPN's to handle this. E.g. with all traffic crossing through your VPC. And with VPN's and network topology, there aren't really any point and click solutions.  Maybe investigating other postgresql sync solutions? Or simply provide periodical data dumps, if the consumers don't need constantly updated data.

Answer (score -1):

Replicating (heh) this idea here now that I know how to actually "answer" questions on SO.

Another possibility is using a dynamic DNS provider. I didn't think of this before because it's basically only used when you want to host a server at home using a connection that uses DHCP, so I don't actually know how well it would work.

Essentially:

1. Sign up with ddns provider like DuckDNS.org.
2. They give you a subdomain at one of their domains, like flp.duckdns.org.
3. You install an update client on the server.
4. The update client (basically a daemon) checks for IP address updates and then notifies the provider when the IP address changes.
5. The provider updates the A record on their name servers to reflect the change.

I think the update should be nearly immediate, but I'm not sure if propagation delay is limited to hostnames or if A records are actually cached along the way (thus bypassing name server lookups).

A couple of potential issues (besides propagation delays):

1. Would the update client be persisted between reboots, migrations, or other AWS actions? This is mainly a question I have because I don't know how one configures/manages the actual ec2 instances used for RDS. Is it even possible to install something extra on the server?
2. There may be issues with reverse DNS lookups when the IP address resolves to multiple hostnames. This could potentially be solved via multiple network interfaces with different external IPs, but we're back into more infrastructure changes.

I think issue #1 could be solved with a fairly simple Lambda function and event triggers if the dynamic DNS provider had an API.

This is a bit of a stopgap solution, though. I think the VPN and proxy solutions are definitely the more robust options.